# Implementing Hover State on MDC Slider in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, mdc-components

I'm working with MDCSlider and I'm trying to apply hover state when the user selects the thumb, such as the picture below.

Is there any chance that I can achieve this in Swift?

[image]